# Display text based on date in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

EDIT: To try to better clarify what I'm trying to do...I hope! :)

The below code works perfectly without the else in the if statement. It is the "else" I'm trying to add. When I do I get the echo I'm describing in my question below.

Thank you again for your time!

---

To prevent thread revival from 2014...I need to ask a question...

I was wondering if I could get some additional help with something that is starting to bother me.

I'm trying to use the code located on the bottom of this thread ([Display image based on date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217429/display-image-based-on-date-in-php)), modified to display a "default" image if the date is not one defined.

Here is my code:

(Instead of images, I placed 'test#' instead of an image path.)

```
$events = array(
                array(
                      'image' => 'test1',
                      'start' => '05-01',
                      'end' => '06-01'
                     ),
                array(
                      'image' => 'test2',
                      'start' => '07-01',
                      'end' => '08-01'
                     )
               );
```

And the foreach code:

(I have removed the img tag so that it will echo the corresponding 'test#'.)

```
foreach($events as $event) {
if(date('d-m') >= $event['start'] && date('d-m') <= $event['end']) {
echo $event['image'];
} else {
echo 'test3';
};
```

When I use the following, it shows the "test3test2" instead of "test2" only.

I have tried adding "break;" after the else echo. When I do, it removes the valid "test#" and leaves "test3".

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have been kicking this around for two days...

If there is another way of doing this that would be better, please let me know!

Comment: I am wondering, what you are trying to do so far.. In first case (for 5-1 & 6-1), your conditions gets failed, so it prints test3 and in second case, the conditions gets true, so it will print image name - test2..Just remove else if you want to print only image name that matches your condition..

Comment: Thanks Kamal

"modified to display a "default" image if the date is not one defined." I want the else to display a default image if it fails...

Comment: Then sorry but this is confusing, what is your question? Try passing correct date & you'll get default image in else..

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I was clear when I stated "When I use the following, it shows the "test3test2" instead of "test2" only." Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works without the else, remove it. Add the default before the loop.

```
$image = 'test3':

foreach($events as $event) {
    if(date('d-m') >= $event['start'] && date('d-m') <= $event['end']) {
       $image = $event['image'];
       break;
    }
}

echo $image;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was down right determined to use that else that I couldn't see past it!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing string comparison. You need a date comparison. You can convert the date in milliseconds first before you compare.

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert date in milliseconds and then compare as it is shown below.

```
foreach($events as $event) {
   if(strtotime(date('d-m')) >= strtotime($event['start']) && strtotime(date('d-m')) <= strtotime($event['end'])) {
   echo $event['image'];
} else {
   echo 'test3';
}
```

**Edit:** Probably adding year would be useful for better comparison.

```
foreach($events as $event) {
   if(strtotime(date('d-m-2016')) >= strtotime($event['start']."-2016") && strtotime(date('d-m-Y')) <= strtotime($event['end']."-2016")) {
   echo $event['image'];
} else {
   echo 'test3';
}
}
```

Comment: `strtotime()` saves lives.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! @haktan suren

I thought date('d-m') was setting the format? I'm checking out strtotime() and I will look into it further. Thanks! :)

I have a problem though...I'm getting "test1test2".

Comment: You need "year" for better comparison. Try my second edit.

Comment: @HaktanSuren Thanks again,

I tried your second edit, I'm still getting the test1test3.

I would like to thank you for trying to keep the "else" in your solutions for a "if the array fails the if statement".

Comment: date() depends on your server date. Try testing here http://phptester.net/, I get "test3test2".

Comment: @HaktanSuren
I correct for that by using date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

Setting test1's date to 07-01 echo's out test1test3. I'm trying to figure out to keep test3 from showing up when the if statement passes and show test3 instead of test#test3 when it fails...

Comment: @HaktanSuren Thank you very much for your help! Magnus' answer allowed me to get away from the else in the if statement. I am wondering why the else wasn't working though...

Comment: If you do not need else condition just remove it :))

Answer (score 0):

String comparison start from left. In date comparison you must check first yerar, then month and finally day. also use strcmp instead of operators.

```
foreach($events as $event) {
if( strcmp( date('m-d'), $event['start'])>0 .... ) {
echo $event['image'];
} else {
echo 'test3';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$events = array(
    array(
           'image' => 'test1',
           'start' => '05-01',
           'end' => '06-01'
         ),
    array(
           'image' => 'test2',
           'start' => '07-01',
           'end' => '08-01'
         )
   );


foreach($events as $event) {
    list($st_date,$st_month) = explode('-',$event['start']);
    list($end_date,$end_month) = explode('-',$event['end']);
    $cur_date = date('d');
    $cur_month = date('m');
    if( ( $st_date >=  $cur_date &&  $cur_month == $st_month  ) && (   $cur_date <= $end_date  &&  $cur_month == $end_month  )  ){
        echo $event['image'];
    } 

}
```